# Rails actionmailer escaping HTML with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, escaping, actionmailer

I am using Action Mailer and trying to include a link.  For some reason the HTML is being escaped and, rather than showing a link, it is showing:

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/employer?task_review=true">here</a>
```

Instead it should just show the link.  Here is the Ruby:

```
<%= raw(link_to("here", employer_url(:task_review => 'true'))) %>
```

I have also tried:

```
<%= link_to("here", employer_url(:task_review => 'true')).html_safe %>
```

and

```
<%= link_to("here", employer_url(:task_review => 'true')) %>
```

None of them seem to work.  I've looked at other SO answers to similar questions and they all say to use either `raw` or `html_safe`, but neither work.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the email is sent in HTML format? could it be that it is sent in TEXT format?

Comment: I think its in html format.  How do I check / change it?

Comment: Look at the raw message (`More -> show original` in Gmail) and look for `Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"`

Comment: Uri Agassi, you were right.  The file format was .text.erb and should have been .html.erb.  If you post it as an answer, I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description of your problem it looks like the problem is not in the template rendering, but in the content type.

An email client accepts different content types, and renders accordingly - parses and renders the HTML if the content type is `text/html`, or shows the text as-is if the content type is `text/plain`.

Many mailers send mail containing more than one version of the mail (one HTML and one TEXT), to support old mail clients which don't have HTML capabilities.

To check whether the mail your program sent has an HTML version, open its raw message (in Gmail that would be under `More -> show original`) and look for text looking like this:

```
------=_NextPart_001_0048_01CE7CA4.8389CCD0
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset="windows-1255"
```

This means that there is an HTML version of the mail you sent.

If however, all you see is something like:

```
------=_NextPart_001_0048_01CE7CA4.8389CCD0
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="windows-1255"
```

your problem is there. (if both options appear - your mail client may not support HTML)

If you find that you do not send an HTML version, make sure your template file has the extension `.html.erb` rather `.text.erb` (the latter indicates to the mailer that you want a text-only mail format).

Answer (score 0):

in config/environments/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

This may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For ActionMailer you should build the URL with the `url_for` helper because other helpers like `link_to` are not available in `ActionMailer`, or include the helper methods in your `ActionMailer` class:

```
<%= url_for controller: 'login',
               action: 'verify',
               only_path: false,
               host: 'http://myawesomesite.com',
               params: { token: '12hew' } %>
```

Comment: If I do this, how do I control what the link text says?